# Flask-SQLAlchemy: from selected row get list of column names where value equals something

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
progress = Progress.query.get_or_404(name)
```

After getting the "progress" object, instead of checking each column if it equals "yes" I want to get a list of columns with just one of a few queries.

In other words,

```
result = ["foo", "bar"]
```

where "foo" and "bar" columns have value "yes" in "progress" row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, I've solved it with this list comprehension:

```
result = [col for col in progress.__table__.columns.keys() if getattr(progress, col) == "yes"]
```

It would be better if there was a way to use just one query if possible.